# Request Authenticated but response not received to postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to authenticate request manually in spring boot ,for which i have created custom filter

```
public class CustomeFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {


private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
public CustomeFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager= authenticationManager;

}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    User tempUser = new User("ADFXFGDXGDS@Gmail.com",
            "ABC@123",
            true, true, true, true, // logging them in...
            getAuthorities(1) // type is List<GrantedAuthority>
    );
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq
            = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(tempUser, getAuthorities(1));
    authReq.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
    SecurityContext sc= SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    //Authentication authentication= authenticationManager.authenticate(authReq);
    sc.setAuthentication(authReq);
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", sc);
    System.out.println("Request Authenticated ...");

}



public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer access) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(2);

    if (access.compareTo(1) == 0) {
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    }
    else{
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }
    return authList;
}

}
```

this is simple security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class BasicSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Bean
    public CustomeFilter customFilter(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            return new CustomeFilter(authManager(httpSecurity));
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        return (httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, e) -> {
            Map<String, Object> errorObject = new HashMap<>();
            int errorCode = 401;
            errorObject.put("message", "Unauthorized access of protected resource, invalid credentials");
            errorObject.put("error", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            errorObject.put("code", errorCode);
            errorObject.put("timestamp", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
            httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(errorCode);
            httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(errorObject));
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);;
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }


    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public DefaultSecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authz-> authz
                        .requestMatchers("api/v1/servercheck").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(customFilter(httpSecurity), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return httpSecurity.build();

    }
    }
```

i have created api endpoints to test it

```
@GetMapping("/api/v1/accessPrivateRes")
    private String accessPrivateRes() {
        return "This is your Private Res: LFOGANGJASFNASFSGPS#$NSDK#$MFGAASJGOREANSNGSKO343nsdfE@#nd@##n-eRSdfs";
    }
@GetMapping("/api/v1/servercheck")
private String onServerCheckReceived() {
    return "Server Check Successful";
}
```

but while i make request (/api/v1/accessPrivateRes) i get empty body response

[image: postman screenshot]

however api /api/v1/servercheck is working properly.
Can anyone please help me resolve the issue

Comment: And why shouldn't it work properly? You opened that endpoint for everyone, next to that you defined a bean for the entrypoint but haven 't wired that entry point up, so it will use the default one from Spring Security.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have made correction in code , can you please check again

Comment: You still haven't registered the entrypoint with the `HttpSecurity` configuration helper.

Comment: @M.Deinum How can i do that ,can you please clarify with code ?